# How do I get VSCode Vim Extension to Control VSCode Keybindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I am new to VSCode from Vim.

I am trying to get Vim to run the VSCode shortcuts and I can't seem to figure out how to get it going.

for example:

In Vim i use `<leader>t` to open a terminal below. In VSCode this is `Ctr+Shift+`
or `<leader>h` and `<leader>l` to switch between splits is `Ctr+1` and `Ctr+2` in VSCode

I have tried remapping the Vim keys to the VSCode commands like this:

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<leader>", "h"],
        "after": ["<C-1>"]
    },
]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!